# C programming , delete function

Tags: c, fseek

try to use fseek to modify the name 
but it cannot return what result i want which is the name cannot be modify and remain the same

```
struct phonebook { char name[20]; };
struct phonebook a;

char temp[20];
cpPtr=fopen("name.txt","rb");//open the file
while(fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,cpPtr)==1){
    printf("Please enter name :\n");//require user to enter name
    scanf("%s",&temp);//temporary variable
    fflush(stdin);
    if(stricmp(a.name,temp)==0){
        printf("NAME :%s\n",a.name);
        else
            printf("The name is not exist");
        getch();
    }

    printf("Please enter new NAME :");
    scanf("&s",a.name);
    fflush(stdin);
    fseek(cpPtr,-sizeof(a),SEEK_CUR);//is there any wrong with seek?
    fwrite(&a,sizeof(a),1,cpPtr);
    fclose(cpPtr);
    printf("Name is modified");
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Please read your question and see if you can understand what you are asking. I surely can't.

Comment: please show us the definition of 'a'

Comment: i am using fseek to find my "name" in the file ,then replace the name but it cant work

Comment: struct phonebook
{
 char name[20];
};
struct phonebook a;

Comment: using fflush(stdin); and scanf(...); [instead of fscanf(stdin);] makes my symmetric detector shiver.

Comment: just my holy war: NEVER you scanf(%s) for user input. Do not even think about it. scanf has no boundary check.

Answer (score 2):

You open the file only for reading. You have to open the file in read-write mode if you want to both read and write.

```
fopen("name.txt","r+b"); // open read+write
```

Comment: after i did that , I also cant modify my name , it also remain the same

Comment: Add debugging statements to see what the program is doing.